# An issue with ncview (netCDF visual browser) on cygwin - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, make, configure, cygwin-x

I have an issue with [`ncview`](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) on [`cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/). Can anyone help?

I have installed `cygwin` on `windows 10` and followed the instructions on [Ncview under Windows](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_win.html).

my output from `./configure` and `make install` are as follows:

```
pclink@DESKTOP-E6T9S2B /home/ncview-2.1.1
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/bjd
checking for nc-config... yes
Netcdf library version: netCDF 4.6.1
Netcdf library has version 4 interface present: yes
Netcdf library was compiled with C compiler: gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for X... libraries , headers
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking for the Athena widgets...
checking for XtWindow in -lXt... yes
checking for XawScrollbarSetThumb in -lXaw... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking X11/Intrinsic.h usability... yes
checking X11/Intrinsic.h presence... yes
checking for X11/Intrinsic.h... yes
checking X11/Xaw/Simple.h usability... yes
checking X11/Xaw/Simple.h presence... yes
checking for X11/Xaw/Simple.h... yes
X Athena widget (Xaw) libraries: -lXaw -lXt
checking for X11 library...
checking for XPutImage in -lX11... yes
X11 libraries: -lX11
checking udunits2.h usability... yes
checking udunits2.h presence... yes
checking for udunits2.h... yes
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... yes
checking for expat library (required by udunits2)...
checking for XML_GetBase in -lexpat... yes
Expat libraries (needed by udunits2): -lexpat -L. -ludunits2
****************************************************************************
Udunits library version 2 support enabled.
udunits2 dirs: include: .  library: .  libname: udunits2
****************************************************************************
checking png.h usability... yes
checking png.h presence... yes
checking for png.h... yes
checking for png_write_png in -lpng... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands

----------- Configure Summary ----------
Compiler:
        CC                 = gcc
        Runtime path flags =  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib

UDUNITS:
        UDUNITS2_LIBS     = -ludunits2
        UDUNITS2_CPPFLAGS = -I.
        UDUNITS2_LDFLAGS  = -L. -ludunits2 -lexpat -L. -ludunits2


NETCDF:
        VERSION          = netCDF 4.6.1
        COMPILER USED    = gcc
        NETCDF_CPPFLAGS  = -I/usr/include
        NETCDF_LDFLAGS   = -L/usr/lib -lnetcdf
        NETCDF_V4        = yes

X:
        X_CFLAGS         =
        X11_LIBS         = -lX11
        XAW_LIBS         = -lXaw -lXt
        X_PRE_LIBS       =  -lSM -lICE
        X_LIBS           =
        X_EXTRA_LIBS     =

PNG:
        PNG_LIBS         = -lpng
        PNG_CPPFLAGS     = -I.
        PNG_LDFLAGS      = -L. -lpng


pclink@DESKTOP-E6T9S2B /home/ncview-2.1.1
$ make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1/src'
test -z "/home/bjd/bin" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/home/bjd/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c 'ncview.exe' '/home/bjd/bin/ncview.exe'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ncview-2.1.1'

pclink@DESKTOP-E6T9S2B /home/ncview-2.1.1
$ ls
"'"               bw.ncmap       config.status   depcomp        install-appdef   missing              README_LOCAL
 3gauss.ncmap     ChangeLog      configure       detail.ncmap   install-sh       Ncview-appdefaults   regenerate
 3saw.ncmap       config.h       configure.in    geteuid        m4macros         NEWS                 RELEASE_NOTES
 aclocal.m4       config.h.in    COPYING         hotres.ncmap   Makefile         README               src
 AUTHORS          config.h.in~   data            hotres.Rmap    Makefile.am      README.sgi           stamp-h1
 autom4te.cache   config.log     default.ncmap   INSTALL        Makefile.in      README.solaris       tt
```

But when I try and run an `nc` file with `ncview WW3_AT_metop_2018_6a_c01_p002.nc`, I receive the following error message:

```
$ ncview WW3_AT_metop_2018_6a_c01_p002.nc
-bash: ncview: command not found
```

I discovered the proper execution command should be as follows, although it still gives and error message:

```
$ /home/bjd/bin/ncview.exe WW3_AT_metop_2018_6a_grid_p071.nc
Ncview 2.1.1 David W. Pierce  1 Aug 2011
http://meteora.ucsd.edu:80/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html
Copyright (C) 1993 through 2011, David W. Pierce
Ncview comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `ncview -w'.
This is free software licensed under the Gnu General Public License version 3; type `ncview -c' for redistribution details.

Note: could not open file /home/pclink/.ncviewrc for reading
Error: Can't open display:
```

Comment: I'm not sure? I may not have installed `gnuplot` and `x11` properly, so I am doing that at the moment, with Install/update Cygwin (`setup-x86_64.exe`).

Comment: ncview 2.1.7 is already available as cygwin package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing `ncview` via `cygwin` update.

`Cygwin` updates when you install the various new files through the installation process - where it just adds those files to the `cygwin` already installed.

I needed to get `gnuplot` working, by exporting the following environmental variable, and adding it to `~/.bash_profile`:

`export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` , from:

[Cygwin on Windows: Can't open display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227889/cygwin-on-windows-cant-open-display)

Comment: If you run gnuplot from Xterm, the `DISPLAY` is automatically set